# Font awesome icons are not visible in chrome print

Tags: html, web, printing, frontend, font-awesome

We are using font awesome icons but all of a sudden the icons are not showing up while printing.

Yet those are visible everywhere else on the entire site. Just not while printing.

All the related assets like fonts and css are loaded locally from the site.

I have checked the @media print visibility and display attribute they are visible and block only.

Answer (score -1):

When I used Web Fonts+CSS approach the icons did not show in pdf.

```
<link href="~/icons/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="~/icons/fontawesome/css/brands.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="~/icons/fontawesome/css/solid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Try to set up Font Awesome  with SVG+JS:

```
<script defer src="~/icons/fontawesome/js/fontawesome.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="~/icons/fontawesome/js/brands.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="~/icons/fontawesome/js/solid.min.js"></script>
```